# Hospedar site em laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, virtualhost

Tenho um projeto em Laravel. Quando eu coloco meus arquivos para o meu servidor de hospedagem e acesso o domínio, ele me mostra os arquivos e pastas em vez de me redirecionar para a index.

Na minha máquina eu crio um virtualhost apontando para a pasta public, onde se encontra o .htaccess. Porém no meu servidor de hospedagem eu não sei como fazer esse redirecionamento.

Eu uso a hospedagem da HostGator e coloco os arquivos no servidor, via FTP. Dentro da pasta public_html.

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score -1):

Na sua pasta public_html do servidor, coloca todos os arquivos da pasta public do seu projeto.

Agora na raiz do seu servidor (fora da public_html), você faz o upload de todos os demais arquivos.

Segue [Fonte](https://cursos.alura.com.br/forum/topico-como-subir-aplicacao-alguma-hospedagem-26567).

Comment: Boa tarde. Eu consegui de outra maneira. Coloquei um outro .htaccess na raiz do meu projeto e resolveu.